# Extracting data from pyephem date string in Python

Tags: python, pyephem

I want to extract the sunrise hour and if I do the following

```
sun = ephem.Sun()
r1 = home.next_rising(sun)
print ("Visual sunrise %s" % r1)
risehr = r1[10:12]
print ("Rise Hour = %s" % risehr)
```

I got the error

```
>>'ephem.Date' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I can print the string `r1` but not extract from it (?)
I tried solutions from similar problem posts on extraction but couldn't make any progress, apologies if this appears to be a double post.

Comment: when you print it it's converted to a string, like `str(r1)`, do you want to take a slice of that? I.E. `str(r1)[10:12]`

Comment: where is the assignment statement for `home`?

Comment: Sorry, 'home' is my lat/long def

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question you want to print only hour of sunrise. `r1` is object of [ephem.Date type](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/date.html). You could make it with brute force

```
...
risehr = str(r1)[10:12]
...
```

or you could convert `r1` object to `datetime`, and `datetime` to `str` representation

```
...
risehr = r1.datetime().strftime('%H') 
...
```

or convert it to `tuple` first

```
...
risehr = r1.tuple()[3]
...
```

All available options you could read at [this page](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/date.html) in section `Conversions`.

Comment: Many thanks. Brute force works fine, I'll try the more elegant method too.

Answer (score 2):

@kvorobiev answered the question of how to extract from a string representation of your data. But the other half of your question was the error:

`'ephem.Date' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

According to the [PyEphem documentation](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#transit-rising-setting) for the `next_rising()` function,

> If the search is successful, returns a Date value.

[Furthermore, `Date` objects have an important property](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#dates):

> Dates are stored and returned as floats. Only when printed, passed to str(), or formatted with '%s' does a date express itself as a string giving the calendar day and time.

When you gave the command `risehr = r1[10:12]`, the Python interpreter attempted to get call [Date.**getattr**()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to get the fields from a Date object corresponding to the slice `10:12`. Without that method, slicing has no meaning to a Date object.

But all is not lost! You can still get the `Date` object's time information:

> Call .tuple() to split a date into its year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

You can then slice this tuple as needed to get the hour:

`hour = r1.tuple()[3]`

Or exhaustively:

`year, month, day, hour, minute, second = r1.tuple()`

Comment: The tuple approach seems really neat. I've learnt a lot from all the helpful responses to my simple problem. Many thanks everyone for the very informative feedback.